# Display javascript object in tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code below that is a HTML page consisting of a tab i want to use my JavaScript multidimensional Array and get each `first name` and `age` to populate the `<h3>` separately is there any simple way to accomplish this any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

var personArr = [];
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:21};
var person2 = {firstName:"Paul", lastName:"Logan", age:22};
var person3 = {firstName:"Sean", lastName:"Kim", age:32};
var person4 = {firstName:"Ken", lastName:"Chow", age:12};

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.line1{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
</div>

<div id="People" class="tabcontent">
<div class="line1">
<h3>Name 1 :</h3>   
<h3>Age 1 :</h3>

<h3>Name 2 :</h3>   
<h3>Age 2 :</h3>

<h3>Name 3 :</h3>   
<h3>Age 3 :</h3>

<h3>Name 4 :</h3>   
<h3>Age 4 :</h3>
 </div>
 </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can the html be modify. By this I mean adding an ``ID`` and a ``class`` to multiple elements?\

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO erm yes as long each name and age are seperated

Comment: Easiest would be to replace the `innerHtml` of $('.line1') with the contents concatenated string of `H3`s for each array element outputted. you get my meaning?

Comment: @SebastianScholle Sorry i dont really get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to move the HTML but you could use some classes and/or id's to make the JS a little more readable.

First you need to get all of the h3's. This can be accomplish by targetting the parent div with class `line1` and getting all of the children.

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0].children;
```

Then you can loop this array and you object array to fill all the innerHTML. Carefull here, you are adding to the innerHTML not changing it.

This llop can be accomplish in a lot of ways, I took a simple one by looping every 2 `h3` tags and keeping a flag of what person is to be added

```
   var personFlag = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < parent.length; i=i+2){
      parent[i].innerHTML += personArr[personFlag].firstName +' '+personArr[personFlag].lastName;
      parent[i+1].innerHTML += personArr[personFlag].age;
      personFlag++
    }
```

Hope this helps :>

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

var personArr = [];
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:21};
var person2 = {firstName:"Paul", lastName:"Logan", age:22};
var person3 = {firstName:"Sean", lastName:"Kim", age:32};
var person4 = {firstName:"Ken", lastName:"Chow", age:12};

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0].children;
console.log(parent);
var personFlag = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < parent.length; i=i+2){
  parent[i].innerHTML += personArr[personFlag].firstName +' '+personArr[personFlag].lastName;
  parent[i+1].innerHTML += personArr[personFlag].age;
  personFlag++
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.line1{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
</div>

<div id="People" class="tabcontent">
<div class="line1">
<h3>Name 1 :</h3>   
<h3>Age 1 :</h3>

<h3>Name 2 :</h3>   
<h3>Age 2 :</h3>

<h3>Name 3 :</h3>   
<h3>Age 3 :</h3>

<h3>Name 4 :</h3>   
<h3>Age 4 :</h3>
 </div>
 </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also create the `<h3>` tags dynamically and append them to the `line1` div. Then, much like Gerardo's answer, you can use a loop to go over each array item and assign it an `<h3>`.

```js
var personArr = [],
    person    = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:21},
    person2   = {firstName:"Paul", lastName:"Logan", age:22},
    person3   = {firstName:"Sean", lastName:"Kim", age:32},
    person4   = {firstName:"Ken", lastName:"Chow", age:12},
    hold      = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0],
    output    = '';
    
personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);

for (var i = 0; i < personArr.length; i++) {
  output += '<h3>Name ' + (i + 1) + ': ' + personArr[i].firstName + '</h3>';
  output += '<h3>Age ' + (i + 1) + ': ' + personArr[i].age + '</h3>';
}

hold.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div class='line1'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always make a string from your array, and then change the innerHTML property of container element(".line1"). it would look like something like this:

`var innerHtmlString = personArr.map(function(person){
        return "<h3>" + person.name + "</h3> <h3>" + person.age + "</h3>"
}).join("\n")
document.querySelector(".line1").innerHTML = innerHtmlString`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this after your javascript:

```
var tagList = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");

var j=0;
for(var i=0;i<tagList.length;i++){

  tagList[i].innerHTML=personArr[j].lastName+" "+personArr[j].firstName;
  i++;
  tagList[i].innerHTML=personArr[j].age;
j++
}
```

Comment: Iterating over tagList !!, why ?